# jqgrid scroll is not working when grouping is enable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

I am working in "jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1" version of jqgrid. I have huge data to show in grid that's why I need dynamic loading on scroll. I set scroll to 1 its working fine without grouping. Following is the example of using scroll but grouping is set to false.

```
{
....
rownum: 30,
scroll: 1,
grouping: false, 
groupingView : { 
    groupField : ['BillTitle'],
    groupColumnShow : [true], 
    groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'], 
    groupCollapse : false, 
    groupOrder: ['asc'], 
    groupSummary : [true], 
    groupDataSorted : true    
   }, 
}
```

On the other end I need to use grouping of jqgrid, when I set grouping to true dynamic loading of scroll not working. Following is not working but I need both functionality.

```
{
....
rownum: 30,
scroll: 1,
grouping: true, 
groupingView : { 
    groupField : ['BillTitle'],
    groupColumnShow : [true], 
    groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'], 
    groupCollapse : false, 
    groupOrder: ['asc'], 
    groupSummary : [true], 
    groupDataSorted : true    
   }, 
}
```

Please help me. Your help should be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the [wiki page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping) says:

**Limitations**

When the grouping is enabled, the following options will be set explicit into the code:

```
scroll = false;
rownumbers = false;
treeGrid = false;
gridview = true (afterInsertRow does not fire too);
```

I ran into the same problem.
For now, there is no option to achieve this, but it would be very nice. Maybe with some code editing.

Comment: Did anybody found the answer? I need for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, but discovered that if you set rowNum to -1 it will show all your grouped data. The odd thing is that on the documentation the -1 option on the rowNum is clearly removed: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options