# jqgrid Grouping & Scroll together

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Trying to enable grouping and also vertical scroll at the same time but that is not possible as per the wiki page (Limitations).

Or Please suggest some other JS Grid library with supports both. Thanks!

[jqgrid scroll is not working when grouping is enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157408/jqgrid-scroll-is-not-working-when-grouping-is-enable)

Comment: Do you really need **virtual scrolling** (`scroll: 1`) where limitation exists (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#limitations)) or you need simple **vertical scrolling**. To get vertical scrollbars you need just specify `height` parameter in the grid with small enough value.

Comment: Yes I need both Grouping & Virtual scroll together.  
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I personally don't like the implementation of virtual scrolling in jqGrid and never use the feature. I don't think that one can implement your requirement in the simple way. Sorry for negative news.

Comment: Its fine Oleg , completely agree. I tend to post this after searching the web , just need suggestions on this thought , if I Set the height and use a custom "jquery scrollbar plugin". May I know will I be able to achieve scroll & grouping together. Haven't tried yet.

Comment: I don't understand why you need any plugin. **How many rows you need to display in the grid?** Which `datatype` you use? Why not just to remove `scroll: 1` and set some `height` option?

Comment: Want to implement custom scroll to handle virtual scroll with grouping. I have around 10k records and 50 records will be visible on the screen with grouping. If in case I rely on the inbuilt vertical scroll then I wouldnt be able to load the more records during runtime.

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle for the same so we can help you with exact problem. thank you

Comment: @Anandh: You wrote that you want to display "around 10k records and 50 records". No user will look through the 10k records. I answered in many my old answers that in my opinion it's the mostly important to provide the user good **filtering** possibility in the grid. The user need to see 5-25 rows from the 10k records, but the rows should have specific criteria. So in my opinion you can use *any paging* (like standard non-virtual), but you should provide user friendly filtering. In the case you will don't need virtual scrolling and the problem will not exist.

Answer (score 1):

jqWidget are my favorite library actually.
The table also supports grouping and sorting.

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-grouping.htm

For personal use it is free

Comment: Right it seems to provide you with both grouping and scrolling. Give it a try.